# how to represent the dot symbol on iPhone

Tags: iphone, nsstring, symbols

I want to show something like the following in my app, but I don't know how to put the dot symbol in a NSString, any helps? Or do I have to use image for the dots?

```
squares (dot) triangles (dot) rectangles
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use option-8 to generate the symbol "•" .